# How to configure PagaVCS(Svn client) for Google code repository

Tags: 12.04, svn

I want to configure PagaVCS for google code repo. How do I add user name password and create commits to the Google repo using the client.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a commit and it'll ask for username/password.

If it doesn't occur for some reason go to: context menu in Nautilus -> PagaVCS -> Settings -> Force login dialog once and retry the commit.